# How to receive multiple packets using UdpClient class?

Tags: c#, udp, client-server, udpclient

First of all, sorry for my bad English. I made a simple client/server program using UdpClient in C#. I have a problem. In order to send a big file (like a pdf for example), I use this code on client-side:

```
    private void WorkOnBuffer(byte[] buffer)
    {
        int cnt = buffer.Length/buffMax; //buffMax = 64000
        byte[] subBuffer = new byte[buffMax];
        int min = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            Array.Copy(buffer, min, subBuffer, 0, buffMax);
            client.Send(subBuffer, subBuffer.Length);
            min += buffMax;
        }
    }
```

There is a loop which send bytes sub-array, made from main bytes array (for example, from pdf or txt). On server-side, how I can read all these packets? With method:

```
client.Receive(ref endPoint)  // endpoint instance of IPEndPoint
```

I read only one array byte. What's my mistake?

Comment: UDP is quite frankly an odd choice for sending large sequential data. Is there any specific reason you chose it over TCP?

Comment: Mind that using UDP and thus sending the data in chunks, you need to manually account for lost packets, out-of-order packets etc. So you need to be able to reconstruct not only the data chunk itself but also its position in the complete data set. And possibly request re-sending of specific packets. Which is all accounted for using TCP.

Comment: If your goal is a "Simple client server program" I would really recommend using a higher level protocol, I found MQTT fairly easy to use, but there are many others, like the ubiquitous Http. Using either TCP or UDP will require you to handle a bunch of low level details that greatly complicates the implementation.

Comment: I know TCP, unfortunately I need to use UDP at work. For these reason need to understand how works UDP and how work a client/server system with UDP.

Comment: Well, that's a little bit too broad for this format. There really is _a lot_ to it (and a lot you can do wrong). Can we boil it down to the specific problem that you are facing _right now_ which seems to be that you are not receiving what you expect, right? Can you post a little more context around the receiving code?